# PHP: Sorting a associative multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a associate multidimensional array here but I am trying to make the names print in ascending order, as well as the date printing in ascending order. However I am fairly new to php and I am not sure how to make that happen. I read to use the array_multisort function but I'm not sure if I have done it right. Can anyone help me out or tell me where I am going wrong?

```
$win = [ 
    'Jane Doe' => '7 October 2015'."<br/>", 
    'Nash Patel' => '14 October 2014'."<br/>", 
    'Joe Public' => '12 October 2016'."<br/>" 
        ];
        foreach($win as $key => $ent) { 
     echo '<strong>' . $key . '</strong> - ' . $ent . PHP_EOL; 
     } 
    foreach($win as $c=>$key) {
            $sort_date[] = $key['Date'];
            $sort_name[] = $key['Name'];
        }

        array_multisort(SORT_ASC, SORT_ASC, $win);
        print_r($win);
```

Comment: So you want `$win` sorted by the key? Use [`ksort()`](http://php.net/ksort)

Comment: http://au2.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php

Comment: Do you mean that if the name is the same then sort by date, otherwise sort by name?

Comment: No I just want to print the names in ascending order, and the dates in ascending order, but they can be seperate prints

Comment: Why are the names and dates together?  printing them the way you want would break any relationship they have.  If they have no relationship, I would build a separate array for the dates, using a time-stamp for the key, it would make it sort better.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I don't mind breaking the relationship as I just need to print them so they are in ascending order. But is this the way or along the lines to doing that?

Comment: @madoreo - that's what I would do, your second foreach loop is 1/2 way there, the first loop, is pointless.  Separate them,sort them, print them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    'Jane Doe'   => '7 October 2015'."<br/>", 
    'Nash Patel' => '14 October 2014'."<br/>", 
    'Joe Public' => '12 October 2016'."<br/>" 
);

foreach( $arr as $k => $v )
{
    $names[] = $k;

    $d = str_replace('<br/>','',$v);
    $dates[] = DateTime::createFromFormat('j F Y', $d );
}

sort( $names );
sort( $dates );

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $names );
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
foreach( $dates as $date )
{
    $formatted_dates[] = $date->format('j F Y');
}
print_r( $formatted_dates );
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have a long way:

- `array_multisort` is used to sort by 'multiple criteria' (like Brian Gottier asked you in the comments), you sort the first array, then, those equal values are sorted by a second criteria. And it looks this is not what you want.
- in a `foreach($win as $c=>$key)`, `$c` is receiving the keys (e.g. `'Jane Doe'` ), and `$key` is receiving values (e.g. `'7 October 2015'."<br/>"`). So when you try to access `$key['Date']` you are trying to access a key (called 'Date') of a string! It doesn't make sense. You should do:

  ```
  foreach($win as $key=>$value) {
      $sort_date[] = strip_tags($value);    
      $sort_name[] = $key;
  }
  ```

Notice that I used `strip_tags` to remove the `<br/>` at the end.

- Now you can easily sort the names:

  ```
  asort($sort_name)
  ```
- To sort dates, if you don't convert them, they are going to be sorted like strings, so you would end up with: `'12 October 2016'`, `'14 October 2014'`, `'7 October 2015'`. So you should use a custom function to sort, that first converts (using `strtotime`) the date to a 'comparable value':

  ```
  function cmp($a, $b){   
      return (strtotime($a) < strtotime($b)) ? -1 : 1;
  }
  uasort ($sort_date,"cmp");
  ```